# What is the difference between BeanPropertyRowMapper and ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I just started to learn Spring (3.2.8) and come across this question:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc = (NamedParameterJdbcTemplate)ctx.getBean("namedjdbc");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("rownum", 10);
params.put("variablename", "FlyMark");

List<Variable> variables = jdbc.query(
        "select materialname, variablename, variablevalue " +
        "from tbl_variables " +
        "where variablename = :variablename and rownum < :rownum",
        params,
        //BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Variable.class)
        ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Variable.class)
        );
```

It seems if I replace `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` with `BeanPropertyRowMapper`, it works too and nothing different.

So my question is: what is `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` designed for?

Comment: They are both the same, check the source. The `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` was added in the time the `RowMapper` wasn't parameterized. There was a `ParameterizedRowMapper`  interface, this was due to the fact earlier versions of Spring were compatible with java versions < 1.5. As of now Java 1.5 > is required and that basically deprecates the `ParameterizedRowMapper` and its implementations. This is also mentioned in the javadoc of those classes.

Comment: I've put the comment into an answer (and extended it a little) please tag it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring 3.0 the `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` and `BeanPropertyRowMapper` are the same.

The `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` (actually everything in the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple` package) was added in the time that Spring was compatible with java version < 1.5 which didn't had generics. To work around this restriction basically 2 implementations of classes started to emerge (one with and one without generics).

As of Spring 3.0 the minimum supported java version has been brought back to 1.5 and as such the seperate packages where merged into the core of the framework and made those parameterized versions obsolote. Most of the code (for instance `SimpleJdbcTemplate`) is deprecated or at least should be considered deprecated. They are still there for backwards compatibility but will probably be removed in the next major release of Spring.

Links

1. [`ParameterizedRowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper.html)
2. [`SimpleJdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html)